# Does the keyword NEW have the per-connection basis aspect to it?

Tags: mysql

I am watching a mysql table with an after insert trigger and i have started to receive many inserts.I am using `NEW.message` to get the last inserted message.

Since i am receiving many inserts from many clients,i am thinking there could be a time that two records are inserted concurrently.I know that the OLD and NEW keywords enable you me access columns in the rows affected by a trigger,but does `NEW` have per-connection uniqueness just like `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger is fired by a SQL statement that makes changes to data in the table for which it is defined. It is important to note that triggers are executed [for each row](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-A-5-1-3) of data affected, not for each statement executed. Therefore the scope of `new` is actually more limited than session variables (which are connection-specific). The `new` and `old` aliases exist only within the local scope of the trigger, so concurrency should not be an issue as long as it is handled correctly in any stored programs which cause a trigger to fire.